# Eclipse EE Palette is not available

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, palette

I am using Eclipse for Java EE developers (Luna). And I am trying to get a palette with the JSP/HTML controls to work for .jsp pages. However, in the Palette tab it says: A palette is not available. Even though I have a .jsp html page opened.
Here is the screenshot:
[image]

How can I get it to work? Is there a palette for jsp in Eclipse Luna, for Java EE developers, or do I need a plugin for it?

Comment: With which editor are you opening your files? It should be the `Web Page Editor`.

Comment: @nitind ok, thanks, i was using the regular one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the JSP file with the *Web Page Editor*. The  *JSP Editor* is source-only, and does not offer contents for the Palette View.

Comment: But, will Web Page Editor support the java scriptlets, declarations, etc. (including auto-completion and formatting?